# Handle orientation changed

Tags: java, android, android-studio, orientation

I am trying to handle change orientation. I enforce orientation in Manifest:

```
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Then in Activity I set onConfigurationChanged, but it doesn't work. It doesn't handle the change orientation. When I don't set orientation in Manifest, everything works perfect, but I need landscape when the activity starts.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {

        startActivity(
                new Intent(GraphActivity.this, MainActivity.class)
                        .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP));

    }
}
```

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

`onConfigurationChanged` won't be called if you have set fixed orientation in manifest

what if user runs app in portrait? it will start with horizontal layout, then if user still want to be in portrait then he must rotate device to landscape and back again to portrait? your described behavior looks to me like bad UX...

but, answering: there is no `"landscape-only-on-start"` for `screenOrientation`... if you really want to program such behavior then you have to use some code, especially `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);` method, but probably also some manual orientation calculation ([sensor callbacks](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_position))

Comment: I looking for solution when i rotate previous activity to landscape it starts ChartActivity this works, but then there is another way how to start ChartActivity and it is click button. In this way user can be at previous activity at Portrait. So i want the ChartActivity will always start at landscape but after ChartActivity rotate to portrait it wil start previous Activity. I tried   setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); but its same like screenOrientation.